# Reading from a file and writing to another file

Tags: python, file, input

I have a question about a project I am working on. I tried to search answers for my questions on the internet, but I couldn't find any. So here I am..
I have a txt file with questions in it (underneath each other) and I want to ask these questions 1 by 1 to the user. When the question is asked, I want the user to give a input ("Y" or "N"). If the answer is "Y" or "N", I want to write the question that is asked and the input that is given, in another empty txt file. If the answer is neither a "Y" or "N", I want to print that the given input is not valid, and after the print statement, I want to ask the same question again.

After the input, I want to repeat this process again, but with the next question, until I ran out of the questions I have in my txt file.

I know that it is not much, but this is my code now:

```
def import_vragenlijst():

    with open ("vragen.txt", "r") as rf:
        lezen = rf.readline()
        print(lezen)
        # with open ("antwoorden_gebruiker.txt", "w") as wf:
        


def main():
    # naam()
    import_vragenlijst()
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to break up the task into smaller parts that you can work on individually.

- Read the question list from one file
- Write the question/answer lines to another file
- Present a question to the user
- Collect the user's answer
- Determine if the response is valid

Unless you anticipate having an enormous question list, consider reading the whole list into an array. Likewise, consider writing your answers to an array before trying to write them out to the file, unless there is some reason they need to be written while a user is answering.

so you'd have something like this (not tested, don't assume it will work without some effort on your part):

```py
def query_user(question):
   response = input(question)
   if is_valid(response):
      return response
   else:
      print(f'{response} is not valid, must by "Y" or "N"')
      # recur, asking the user again
      return query_user(question)
   
def is_valid(response):
  return response == "Y" or response == "N"

def main():
   # open up the file, then read all the questions into memory
   with open(question_filename, "r") as questions_file:
       questions = [question for question in questions_file.read()]
   
   # create an array of answers based on user input
   answers = [query_user(question) for question in questions]

   # open the answers file and write the questions and answers out
   with open(answered_questions_filename, "w") as answers_file:
       for question, answer in zip(questions, answers):
           answers_file.writeline(question)
           answers_file.writeline(answer)
```